# Can I earn reputation points through flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, reputation

It's been two months since I joined the community but still some things are not yet clear to me. I flagged 6 questions that were helpful.Is there any threshold number of helpful flags that will give a little bump in my reputation points? I am talking about my Stack Overflow account, not the Meta account.

Comment: _"Can I earn reputation points through flags?"_ Short and simple answer: No you can't.

Comment: Checking the help center would've answered that. But yeah, panta has the gist of it.

Comment: Not even a badge?

Comment: AGAIN.... help center should answer that (less subtle hint: Not to be rude, really. but on meta like on the main site you are supposed to do your research. It's not like you can't check around for the questions you're currently asking. If you can't find it, for sure ask and we'll be happy to answer though ^^)

Comment: Related MSE discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80852/why-there-isnt-reputation-points-for-successful-flagging

Comment: @Patrice this is far from being trivial. There is no single help center page saying outright "helpful flags don't give any reputation". Such questions are perfectly valid in meta sites.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No**, helpful flags don't give you any reputation.

But you can get a few badges:

- [Citizen Patrol](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol): First flagged post
- [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy): Raise 80 helpful flags
- [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal): Raise 500 helpful flags